# Chrome headless does not work with Re-direct (OAUTH2)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, protractor, webdriver, chrome-options

When I run my protractor project normally, everything is fine, but in headless mode, it does not work, times-out waiting for the first element I need.

I feel that because the page redirects due to OAUTH2, in headless it fails.

I have tried '--ignore-certificate-errors' but this has not worked for me. I have also tried '--disable-dev-shm-usage' without success. I have tried other ones like ignore ssl errors, localhost, etc, nothing seems to work.

Has anybody run into this issue?

Comment: Did you try to get a screenshot to see where exactly the browser stops?

Comment: Hi @JensDibbern Yes, I just did that, thank you. It turns out my app threw a pre-defined "Unsupported Browser Type"

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by changed `--user-agent` value in chrome args